# Dojo: TabContainer in region 'top' invisible inside BorderContainer

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I want to place a `TabContainer` inside the top region of a `BorderContainer` like this:

```
<div id="appLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 1'">tab 1</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 2'">tab 2</div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">center</div>
</div>​
```

When I try this the `TabContainer` is invisible.
Everything works fine when I place the `TabContainer` in the center region of the `BorderContainer`:

```
<div id="appLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 1'">tab 1</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 2'">tab 2</div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'bottom'">bottom</div>
</div>​
```

Why is the `TabContainer` invisible in the top region? Can I make it be visible?

EDIT: The content of the `TabContainer` has a variable height so I don't want to set the height manually.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height css property of your TabContainer div e.g. like:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'" style="height: 100px;">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: But the content has a variable height, I wanted the TabContainer to adapt the height. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Can we not set the height of the tab container to be 100% ... won't it then be the height of the top region?

Answer (score 1):

Try to resize the root BorderContainer.

It's looks like a some hack, but it works for me:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="rootContainerWidget">
   <!-- content panes, tab containers etc -->
</div>
```

and inside widget code add public **resize** method:

```
resize: function () {
    // resize hack
    this.rootContainerWidget.resize();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't check that, I don't have the code any more. But thanks anyway.